# Android-Studio errors: Condition 'emails.isEmpty()' is always 'false'; Condition 'emails.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()' is always 'false'

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, if-statement, runtime-error

submit.setOnClickListener(v -> {

```
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        EditText name = findViewById(R.id.TextUserName);
        String userName = name.getText().toString().trim();

        EditText email = findViewById(R.id.TextEmailAddress1);
        String emails = email.getText().toString().trim();

        EditText pass = findViewById((R.id.TextPassword1));
        String password = pass.getText().toString().trim();


        if(userName.isEmpty()){
            name.setError("UserName is required");
           name.requestFocus();

        }
        else if(emails.isEmpty()){
            email.setError("Email is required");
            email.requestFocus();

        }
        else if(password.isEmpty()){
            pass.setError("Password is required");
            pass.requestFocus();

        }
        else if(emails.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
         else if(!(emails.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty())){
```

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emails,password).addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, task -> {
if(!task.isSuccessful()){
Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Signup unsuccessful, please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else {
startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
}
});
}
else{
Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});

```
}
```

}

Comment: try adding 'if' only. if your username is not empty, it will not check the rest of the conditions

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using the if-else-if structure that will skip the rest of the conditions if the 1st ever condition is true. The same is the case with you. Whenever your username is not empty, it skips all the rest of the conditions and that looks like the result is false for those ifs
try this

```
if(userName.isEmpty()){
        name.setError("UserName is required");
       name.requestFocus();

    }
     if(emails.isEmpty()){
        email.setError("Email is required");
        email.requestFocus();

    }
     if(password.isEmpty()){
        pass.setError("Password is required");
        pass.requestFocus();

    }
     if(emails.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
      if(!(emails.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()))
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but when I try this method my validations don't work, instead of creating the user profile it jumps back to the login screen without creating the user account/profile

Comment: @zide you should update these lines in your code and let the rest of the code work too